# Endpoint url for rest api using php

Tags: php, apache, rest, mamp

When I used    `Alias /books "C:/MAMP/htdocs/api/index.php"` in `httpd.conf` I get the results for `localhost/books`

This  `read_one.php` actually takes parameters, like `localhost/api/read_one.php?id=2`, How do I specify the paramters in end point url

This does not actually work

```
Alias /books/:id "C:/MAMP/htdocs/api/read_one.php"
```

I want it to work like `localhost/books/2`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Alias as `Alias /books "C:/MAMP/htdocs/api/read_one.php"`.
In localhost simply call: `localhost/books?id=2`

Comment: @MrRobot9 In that case you'll need to rewrite some urls. Check out: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: No it won't. You'll either need to rewrite urls or apply something like Front Controller pattern.